# using cp command without destination operand on large directory does not give error and uses up disk space

Tags: disk-usage, cp

Bit of a strange one here

I was trying to copy data from one directory to another and left off the destination operand from the cp.  See command

```
root@server:/home/pp/test1# cp -r ../dhcppc0/*
```

The command ran for over an hour, as the source directory contained over 135GB of data and a lot of directories.

I monitored this and watched the available disk on the system go down and left it overnight. In the morning, I noted the session to the server had timed out, saw that the available disk space had gone down further but the files/directories were not copied.

On closer inspection, I saw my cp command and noticed that I had forgotten to put a '.' as the second operand to direct the copy to my current directory, and it did NOT give an error?

So my question is, what and where is all the disk space gone? and how to I get it back? is there some temporary buffer space somewhere on the system that I can clear?

The source directory holds about 135GB data in about 1M files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: rsync is much better suited for large file transfers both local and remote, '-avz' are the switches I typically use.

Answer (score 1):

> On closer inspection, I saw my cp command and noticed that I had forgotten to put a '.' as the second operand to direct the copy to my current directory, and it did NOT give an error?

Why should it? In `cp -r ../dhcppc0/*`, `cp` is not handling `../dhcppc0/*`. The shell expands `../dhcppc0/*`, and then passes the expanded content to `cp`. So if it expanded into `../dhcppc0/bar`, `../dhcppc0/baz`, and  `../dhcppc0/foo`, then the expanded command would be:

```
cp -r ../dhcppc0/bar ../dhcppc0/baz ../dhcppc0/foo
```

And if `foo` is a directory, `cp` will happily copy all the content of the other directories to `foo`.

> [W]hat and where is all the disk space gone? and how to I get it back? is there some temporary buffer space somewhere on the system that I can clear?

Do `echo  ../dhcppc0/*`, look at the last name that comes up and inspect that directory.

This is why when copying directories or using wildcards, always use the `-t` paramater:

```
cp -t . ../dhcppc0/*
# or cp --target-directory . ../dhcppc0/*
```

And note that you will miss out on any dot-folders and dot-files if you use `*`. You don't need to use it, so better to simply do:

```
cp -t . ../dhcppc0/
```